# Groovy TemplateEngines giving "Scripts not permitted Error to use new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine ERROR"

Tags: templates, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have to update one variable in template file, so doing it with groovy template engines as below :

```
> def installerTemplate=readFile "${template}" 
>     def binding=[
>             'exeName': exeName
>             ]  
>     def engine=new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()  
>     def tpl=engine.createTemplate(installerTemplate).make(binding) 
>     writeFile file: "${target}", text: "${tpl}".toString()
```

but here, I am getting below permission error!
I saw similar kinda issue here but most of the places solution was to change Jenkins security configuration but in my case that's not the option.
so is there any other way to fix this issue without touching Jenkins configuration.

Or if you could suggest some other approach in groovy than using template!

Any suggestions are really appreciated

Thanks,
Ganesh

```
>     org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
> Scripts not permitted to use new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectNew(StaticWhitelist.java:184)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:148)
>       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:197)
>       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedConstructor(Checker.java:202)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.constructorCall(SandboxInvoker.java:21)
>       at WorkflowScript.createInstallCmdFile(WorkflowScript:76)
>       at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:55)
>       at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:96)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor425.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
>       at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of many signatures requires confirmation and addition to the white page, SimpleTemplateEngine also belongs to them;
I had a task to do what you need;
Here's what I got:

```
private static Object binding1(Map map, String string) {
    Template template = new StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(string)
    return template.make(map.withDefault { "&lt;not found&gt;" })
}
```

But, since you do not have administrator rights for jenkins, you can implement something like this:

```
private static Object binding2(Map map, String string) {
    for (def data : map) {
        string = string.replace("\${" + data.getKey() + "}", data.getValue().toString())
    }
    return string
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks simkin for reply ... I am using simple string replace approach now, which is working like a charm! :)